# Getting an error regarding the depreciation of API 'set value for key on a NSObject'

Tags: swift, xcode10, ios12, swift4.2

Getting an error regarding the depreciation of API 'set value for key on a NSObject'

[image]

I am upgrading my code to Swift 4.2 . While upgrading in runtime the code is crashing at this point.

```
object.setValue(valueToSet, forKey: key)
```

Comment: looking at the error, it seems like the problem is at `streetAddress1` and not the line of code you just posted.

Comment: To make `setValue(_:forKey:)` work, the properties set need to have `@objc`-setter. Have you added `@objc` on such properties? Especially on `streetAddress1`?

Comment: I have created replica classes of all CoreData entities I have, each entity has lots of attribute. I have a common method which maps the all the attribute of the entity to its respective NSObject Classes. So adding @objc to all attribute is the real solution here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have to add `@objcMembers` to the `NSObject` class.